# MSSQL ColumnStore index - use of conventional indexes

Tags: sql-server, indexing, columnstore

Forgive me if this is a simple question but I cannot seem to find any clarity and thought I would post it here.

If I have a table where I have created a columnstore index do I still need conventional indexes?

In my example I have a very big table with 1.2 billion records

it has a columnstore index defined as follows:

```
CREATE CLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE INDEX [IDX_123] 
   ON [dbo].[XXX] 
   WITH (DROP_EXISTING = OFF, COMPRESSION_DELAY = 0)
```

In addition to this the consultancy we have created an additional non clustered rowstore index on each column in the table: We have 30, i.e. 30 additional indexes

From my testing it seems as if the the optimizer just uses the columnstore index in ignores the rowstore indexes and my question is whether these are required at all?

Comment: Please check the documentation - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/columnstore-indexes-overview?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 0):

it's not true, columnstore index can replace Row base index in table scan or index scan  operator, if query need to index seek  ، it will use row base index